# Document library Send to other location is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-server

a user has this option disabled but when i checked the permission. she has full control permission to the library.

[image]

is there any settings we need to set for this?

Comment: What permissions do you have on document library?

Answer (score 0):

I know it will not work in IE9.

Firstly, try using it in different browsers, if the issue is not resolved then try disabling **STSUpld CopyCtl Add-in**.

Good Luck.

Comment: i asked her to try with diff browser and she still cannot perform the action

Answer (score 0):

I need to collect the following information to further troubleshoot the issue:

Open the library in another browser and compare the results.

Check whether the issue exists for other users.

check whether the issue exists in other libraries.

check whether the issue exists in other libraries of different site.

Comment: I will check and get back to you! but she tested with other browsers and issue is still the same

Comment: Is there anything update?

Comment: Hi , sorry yes. we just used the open in explorer feature to move items across libraries. but when i checked, the issue only exists in the Pages (Site Pages) doc lib.